# java.awt.Robot does not work for handling “File Upload” dialog window when executed via Jenkins job

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

Robot class does not work when the selenium suite is executed via a Jenkins job. The same suite however works successfully when executed on local machine.

Need answer for following:

1. Is there any Jenkins plugin or config changes required for Robot class to work on Jenkins ( basically am I missing anything? )
2. Is there any approach that can be leveraged for handling "File Upload" dialog that will run successfully when executed via Jenkins job ?
3. As far as I have searched Robot Class, AutoIt and Sikuli are the 3 approaches for handling Window's dialog popup but which of these is compatible with Jenkins as well ?

Answer (score 0):

For **file uploading**, don't use `Robot` class to do it, **use Selenium**:

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));
element.sendKeys("/full/path/to/your/file");
```

To answer your questions:

1. For Robot to work on Windows Jenkins slave, you need a user to be logged in and the machine not locked, which means, not disconnected (if you'll be connected with RDP to the machine when your code is running, it should work).
2. See the approach I started with, and [see examples](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/best-practices-tips-selenium-file-upload).
3. These 3 frameworks have nothing to do with Jenkins compatibility, they all are for simulating user actions on desktop, so it simply depends on the OS that your Jenkins slave has (AutoIt - Windows only, Sikuli and Robot - all OSs).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it directly, however this approach worked for me, if your developer has used JavaScript for file upload.

```
//The file input element which upon clicking opens the Window's dialogue for file upload
   WebElement fileUploadElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]");

//Absolute Path to the upload file
String absoluteFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//"+"src//main//resources//pictures//somePicture.jpg";

//Replacing the slashes to convert it into Absolute Path.
absoluteFilePath = absoluteFilePath.replace("\\","/");

//un-hide the FlowJS's hidden file uploader with some code like this
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
            "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1",
            fileUploadElement);

//Passing the upload file’s Absolute path to Send Keys 
fileUploadElement.sendKeys(absoluteFilePath );
```

Note:
1) The File path specified must be the absolute path to the file.
2) Make sure you do not click on the file upload Web Element.
Handle any Alerts after the file upload if any are present.

For further documentation from SeleniumHQ click [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#user-content-q-does-webdriver-support-file-uploads)